# How to upgrade simulink lookup blocks to Lookup tables?

Tags: upgrade, simulink, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a simulink model developed in matlab older version. I would like to upgrade the lookup and Lookup2D blocks to 1-D and 2-D Lookup Tables through a matlab script. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have tried slupdate and Upgrade Advisor. The Table data is completely changed. Which is not acceptable to me.

Comment: Above information regarding data changed was wrong. Apologies. I have tried slupdate and Upgrade Advisor. They are not detecting blocks which have library links active. How can include syntax to consider blocks which have library links.

Comment: Are the old blocks from standard Mathworks libraries, or custom libraries?  The standard ones should be replaced by `slupdate` by default.

Comment: Though these old blocks are from std libraray, slupdate or upgrade advisor does not detect blocks with custom library links. I am looking for a syntax to which can upgrade these blocks even though blocks are linked to custom library. Thanks!

Comment: As per my answer, you'll need to write your own function using the MATLAB-Simulink API functions listed.  These are used to load and modify any model from MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0):

The specifics of what you want will depend on the previous version and the new version, and how you are using the blocks.  But in general you might find that using [slupdate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slupdate.html) or [Update Advisor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/upgradeadvisor.html) may already do what you need.

Failing that you'll need to use a collection of functions from the MATLAB-Simulink API, such as [find_system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) and [replace_block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/replace_block.html), possibly along with [set_param](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) and [get_param](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html).